# How to find an invertible matrix to show two other matrices similarity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to show that $A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ -\frac{a^2}{b} & -a\end{pmatrix}$ is similar to $B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ but I can't find an invertible matrix $P$ that $A=PBP^{-1}$.

Comment: Naive approach: assume $P = \begin{pmatrix} c & d \\ e & f \end{pmatrix}$, then solve $AP = PB$ for $c, d, e, f$.

Comment: Note: Given the form of the first matrix, with a $b$ in the denominator, it's OK to assume that $b \ne 0$.

Comment: Select a non-zero solution $x$ to $Ax = 0$ to obtain the second column of $P$, then take any solution $y$ to $Ay = x$ to obtain the first column.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know that *"Two matrices are similar if and only if they represent the same linear transformation with respect to different bases"*.

Let us examine the transformation $T: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R} ^2$ that is defined for all vectors $v \in \Bbb{R}^2$ as follows:
$T(v) = Av$ 
($A$ is the same $A$ matrix in your question);

What is the transformation matrix according to the standard base $E=(\space\space(1,0)\space,\space(0,1)\space\space)$?

Answer: $A$ itself (if you cannot see why, verify with calculating the value of $\space T$ for each of $E$'s vectors).

Now, we know that there exists a base of $\Bbb{R}^2$ that we will notate as $\mathfrak{B} = \{v_1,v_2\}$ , with respect to which the transformation matrix of $T$ is exactly $B$ from your question. Your job is to find such a base (a possible way to do so will written be down).

Note that if $P$ is the change of coordinates matrix between the bases $E$ to $\mathfrak{B}$ , $T$'s representing matrices with respect to them hold the equality: 
$A = P^{-1} B P$.

Finding $P$ is just writing the coordinates of $v_1$ with respect to $E$ as the first column, and $v_2$'s as the second - which means that $v_1$ is the first column of $P$ , and $v_2$ is the second!(because $E$ is the standard base)

---

Now, as promised - A way to find $\mathfrak{B}$:

see that - $T(v_1) = v_2$ , 
$T(v_2) = \underline0 \space$ ($\underline0$ is the zero-vector). 
Calculate $Ker(T)$ , and each vector there is suitable for $v_2$. 
for $v_1$ - you know that $T(v_1) = Av_1$ because of $T$'s definition, but also you know that $T(v_1) = v_2$. 
Now, solve the equation system you will get, find $v_1$, and you have $\mathfrak{B}$!